# Check length of number of files uploaded using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple browse button. I want to show Apply button when I upload file from at least 4 browse button. I can check length of file when I upload file from single browse button. But how can I check files length when I upload files from multiple uploads.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="file" class="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<input type="file" class="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<input type="file" class="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<input type="file" class="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button>Apply</button>
</span>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var allFiles = document.getElementsByClassName('files');

if (allFiles.length > 4) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
} else {
   // code to show apply button
}
```

It's not working well. How can I found the length of total uploaded file?

Comment: Any plans to use jQuery in your code? If so the solution will be much smaller and readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the "change" event of the input elements.

When this event is triggered, you can loop the `fileElements` and check the number of files using `files.length`.
You can then keep track of the number of elements that have more than 0 files.

If all elements have an uploaded file, you can enable the button.

For example:

```js
var fileElements = document.getElementsByClassName('files');

for (var i = 0; i < fileElements.length; i++) {
    fileElements[i].addEventListener("change", countFiles);
}

function countFiles() {
    var elementsWithFiles = 0;

    for (var j = 0; j < fileElements.length; j++) {
        if (fileElements[j].files.length > 0) {
            elementsWithFiles++;
        }
    }

    if (elementsWithFiles > fileElements.length -1) {
        document.getElementById("readBytesButtons").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
.readBytesButtons {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="" name="">
    <input type="file" class="files" name="file"/> Read bytes:
    <input type="file" class="files" name="file"/> Read bytes:
    <input type="file" class="files" name="file"/> Read bytes:
    <input type="file" class="files" name="file"/> Read bytes:
    <span class="readBytesButtons" id="readBytesButtons">
      <button>Apply</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the amount of files inserted you most likely would need to add an event listener to each of the file inputs. Then increasing when an file gets inserted and then check if the required amound is added you would probably end up with something like this:

```
var insertedFiles = 0;

var allFileElements = document.getElementsByClassName('files');

for (var i = allFileElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    allFileElements[i].addEventListener("change",check);
};

function update(){
    if(this.value == "") { 
        insertedFiles--;
    } else {
        insertedFiles++;
    }
    check();
}
function check(){
    if(insertedFiles > 4){
        alert("Show button.");
    } else {
        alert("You need to add more files.");
    }
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aL0qhoe0/2/